# Display image in gridview depending on value of column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which displays rows and columns all linked to an sql statement... and all works as normal.

I want to include a new column, that displays an image depending on what the value of the column is. If the column has a value - it will display an image. If the column value is null no image whill be displayed.

My sql is something like:

```
SELECT c.call_id, title, a.call_id as b_attach
FROM calls c 
LEFT JOIN attachments a ON c.call_id = a.call_id 
GROUP BY c.call_id,title,description, a.call_id
```

What's returns from this sql is:

**Call_id** | **title** | **b_attach**
1235 | title goes here | 1235
1382 | another title    |NULL

So if there's something in b_attach - diplay image in gridview column, else display nothing in gridview column

My Gridview:

```
                        <asp:HyperLinkField SortExpression="call_id" HeaderText="Call id" DataTextField="call_id"
                            DataNavigateUrlFields="call_id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="showcall.aspx?id={0}" />
                        <asp:HyperLinkField SortExpression="Title" HeaderText="Title" DataTextField="title"
                            DataNavigateUrlFields="call_id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="showcall.aspx?id={0}" />

                    </Columns>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TemplateField`, and, inside it something like this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="myImg" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "b_attach")) >%' visible='<%# null != DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "b_attach") %> />
```

Comment: ok this certainly got me on the right track. It didn't work exactly (something to do with null and system.dbnull) which I couldn't seem to get fixed. I changed b_attach to a boolean(bit) when returned, and then could leave out the null part. So just ened up with:  Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "b_attach")%>'   .Image url was just just a straight path to image no code required. Thanks!